# Working with REST API Calls while Using Spring Security Core PlugIn

Tags: java, rest, grails, jax-rs, grails-plugin

I am currently working on Grails Application where I have REST API using jaxr PlugIn. The scenario is that there is a Third Party who says that give us a URL and we will send you the notifications on that URL.So I created a REST API with post method. So I can send data using this post method. So,I gave this URL to that third party which now sends me notifications over that URL. And in the body of that POST method in my REST API gets the notification and do what I want to.

So, I used Spring Security Core to authenticate my other features of application. And I wasn't intended to secure this REST API that I implemented using Jaxr PlugIn. But after using that Spring Security Core plugin my Rest API stopped working as it has restricted this REST API too. I tested it on my machine too and send post requests but this plugin is not allowing me to make request due to authentication issue.

Please guide me that what I should do in this scenario? I don't want to secure my REST, can I proceed with this?

Thanks for your precious time :)

Answer (score 0):

With Spring security you define urls that are secured. Specify correct url patterns and it should be ok.

Comment: grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
 .....
    '/MediaSenseEvents/SessionEvents': ['permitAll'],
    ....
]

I have specified as follow but not authenticating. I get response un-authorized

Comment: Will I have to use "Spring Security Rest" PlugIn ?

Comment: Check that previous rules do not prevent the unauthorized access, by default first found match for url in ruleset is applied. So url for your rest api should be first in rule list